# How to unit test a c# method that has dependency on a locally declared object's behavior?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependencies

I have a c# method that is dependent on the return value of a service call that it makes with an object that is locally instantiated. How can I test it without making change to the code. I am aware that dependency injection would have made it testable or passing dependency to out of this method would make it testable, but that is not the case here.

My method looks something like this:

```
public class Animal
{ 
    int Weight;
    public int CalculateActualWeight()
    {
       var weightFactory = new WeightFactory();
       var weight = Weight + weightFactory.GetEatenAmount();
       return weight;
    }
}
```

The method to be tested is CalculateActualWeight().

Comment: Can you not change the production code at all, or just not change its external interface?  if you pull `var weightFactory = new WeightFactory();` into a function on `Animal` you could self stub in your unit test.  Not your best option, but better than not being able to test it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake the returned result of a function using something like Moq. You can set it up (it your test) so that your dependency returns whatever you tell it to return. Then you can test the dependent method knowing what the result of the other method will be.

```
var mock = new Mock<IYourClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Method()).Returns(true);
```

That will make your Method() always return true so that you can test the other. [More info on Moq here.](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

Comment: This is good.  Note that is will only work if the locally instantiated object in question is created in a different function than the one under test.  If they are in the same function, this will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: And his edit now shows that the object is created in the same function. The only thing I can say is that it's better to write you code with testability in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the production code, the only way to test it would be to write a test that surrounds how the locally instantiated object functions as well.

You could also use `self stubbing`, but that isn't a recommended practice, and will only work if the object under test has functions that can be mocked to replace what you need.

example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    //do stuff so that a "real" new WeightFactory() will return what you want
    //(this will require you to go figure out how the WeightFactory works), 
    //4 is just an example of your desired result
    SetUpSystemSoThatWeightFactoryProduces(4);

    var testAnimal = new Animal();
    testAnimal.Weight = 14;

    Assert.That(testAnimal.CalculateWeight(), Is.EqualTo(18));
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of that with reference to my example question?

Comment: WeigthFactory is instantiated inside CalculateActualWeight(). So, i cannot think of any way to set up WeightFactory.GetEatenAmount() to return what i want, because it is a brand new object that is instantiated inside the method under test.

Comment: You can't stub it out.  You have to go look at the actual implementation of that function, and do whatever it takes to set up the "system" to return the value you want from that function call using the real code.